# Is there a shorthand way of writing a range type in Swift?

Tags: swift

So my knowledge of Swift is that there are convenience syntaxes/shorthand ways of defining certain types that can shorten types for parameters in functions.

e.g. an array,

```
func example(anArray: Array<Int>) {}
```

can be more easily written

```
func example(anArray: [Int]) {}
```

Or with a dictionary,

```
func example2(aDictionary: Dictionary<String, Int>) {}
```

can be more easily written

```
func example2(aDictionary: [String: Int]) {}
```

I was wondering if there was a shorthand way available for a range, or is the following the only way to write it? Not that its very long to write it this way, I'm more just curious!

```
func example3(aRange: Range<Int>) {}
```

Comment: Not for writing the type in the way you are using it. The only shorthand would be type inference in initialization.

Comment: Yea, I figured as much, but I thought I'd ask in case I'd completely missed something (unfortunately not unusual for me lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

The  [Range Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73) are only used for creating ranges, they are not used to define the type.

If you write

```
let arr  = [0, 1, 2]
let dict = [0:0, 1:1, 2:2]
let range= 0...2
```

and inspect all three variables' types, for:

- `arr` you will get `let arr: [Int]`
- `dict` you will get `let dict: [Int : Int]`
- `range` you will get `let range: Range<Int>`

Which leads me to beleive there is no shorthand for defining the range type in Swift.

Comment: Yea I've seen these, but aren't these only for specifying the number when calling the function? e.g. with my function: `example3(3..<5)`

Comment: I was more just curious if there was another way of defining it like `example3(aRange: ..<)` or even something like `example3(aRange: Int...Int)` (I know that they don't work).

Comment: I've updated my answer. There is also a section under Arrays titled `Array Type Shorthand Syntax`, however there is no equivalent for ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range as follows.

```
var range = UInt32(1)...UInt32(100)
```

or

```
var range = UInt32(start)...UInt32(end)
```

I always use this to get a random number from within a specified range.

```
func random(start:UInt32, end:UInt32) -> UInt32 {
    var range = UInt32(start)...UInt32(end)
    return range.startIndex + arc4random_uniform(range.endIndex - range.startIndex)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I do know how to use a range though, I was just wondering if there was another way of defining a range type.

Comment: As an aside, if I were to define a function for getting a random number in a range, I wouldn't bother creating an additional range variable (in case the range is really large) and just go straight for calculating the random number like this (please excuse the lack of multiple lines in this comment): `func random(start: UInt32, end:UInt32) -> UInt32 { return start + arc4random_uniform(end - start + 1) }`